# Python 3's Signal.sigwaitinfo equivalent in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

```
siginfo = signal.sigwaitinfo({signal.SIGUSR1})
    print("py: got %d from %d by user %d\n" % (siginfo.si_signo,
                                             siginfo.si_pid,
                                             siginfo.si_uid))
```

I can do the above in python 3.

Is there an equivalent in python 2.7?

I want to get the signal sender's info

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to call the c standard lib from python.

One way in the python stdlib to use ctypes but  it is quite complicated.

So I give a [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) solution

it's a two step process

first compile a module via running this script. I named this module _siggwaitinfo

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.set_source("_sigwaitinfo","""
#include <signal.h>
""")
print("new")

ffi.cdef("""

// the typedef are not guess by in struct by cffi
typedef int pid_t;  
typedef unsigned int uid_t;


typedef struct  {
  int      si_signo;    /* Signal number */
  pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
  uid_t    si_uid;      /* Real user ID of sending process */
  ...;
} siginfo_t ;

typedef struct {
   ...; } sigset_t;

#define SIGUSR1 ...
#define SIG_BLOCK ...

int sigaddset(sigset_t *set, int signum);
int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *set, sigset_t *oldset);
int sigwaitinfo(const sigset_t *set, siginfo_t *info);
""")

ffi.compile()
```

then use it via a script nearly as simple as your original c code (testing return code is an additional burden add compared to python code. It is let as an exercise to the reader)

```
from _sigwaitinfo import ffi, lib

set = ffi.new("sigset_t *")
info = ffi.new("siginfo_t *")

ret= lib.sigaddset(set,lib.SIGUSR1)
print ("return code of sigaddset",ret)
#a call to sigprocmask is necessary to not die
ret= lib.sigprocmask(lib.SIG_BLOCK,set,ffi.NULL);
print ("return code of sigprocmask",ret)
ret = lib.sigwaitinfo(set,info)
print("return code of sigwaitinfo",ret)
print("py: got %d from %d by user %d\n" % (info.si_signo,
                                           info.si_pid,
                                           info.si_uid))
```